# How can I extend config values

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Example

```
Ext.define('ClassA', {
    plugins: [ 'PluginA' ]
});

Ext.define('ClassB', {
    extend: 'ClassA',
    plugins: [ 'PluginB' ]
});

Ext.create('ClassB', {
    plugins: [ 'PluginC' ]
});
```

So I would like to have an instance of `ClassB` with plugins `PluginA`, `PluginB`, `PluginC`.

Comment: Shouldn't the last be `ClassC`?

Comment: No, he create's an instance of class B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to merge them in the constuctor. Here's a possible solution:

```
Ext.define('ClassA', {
    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this;
        config.plugins = Ext.Array.merge(config.plugins ? config.plugins : [], ['PluginA'])
        Ext.apply(me, config);
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/EGMxA/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work. Cause, there are no property `plugins` on config object. So `PluginC` from creation will not be applied to instance.

But this worked for me:

```
constructor: function(config) {
    this.plugins = Ext.Array.merge(this.plugins || [], [
        'PluginA'
    ]);
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

I'm using Ext version 4.1.1.1